# Postfix operator along with comparison

Tags: java, anagram

`s1 and s2` are `strings.char_count[26]` is an integer array for storing count of characters.This is one of the solution for finding difference between 2 strings to be anagrams. Can anyone explain this code?

````
int char_count[] = new int[26];

                for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) 
                    char_count[s1.charAt(i) - 'a']++;        
                for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {

                    if(char_count[s2.charAt(i)-'a']--<=0)
                        count++;
         ```
````

Comment: You posted partial code that doesn't pass compilation, so it's not possible to explain this code. We don't know what `count` is. There's only one `String`. You probably meant to call `charAt` for some `String`. etc...

Comment: There should be 3 loops: first you iterate s1 and increment counters in `char_count`, second you iterate s2 and decrement counters in `char_count`, third you iterate `char_count` and make sure that all elements are 0 - then s1 and s2 are anagrams.